# Directly pass from transform feedback buffer to fragment shader

Tags: opengl, transformation, shadow-mapping, level-of-detail

I am building terrain using a lod algorithm and deferred cascaded shadowmaps. The tessellated terrain is about 6,000,000 triangles. I tried this using 2 methods.

1st method: Both the deferred shadow program and the drawing program use tessellation shaders to tessellate the terrain. The tessellation stage for each program is exactly the same.

2nd method: I have 3 programs. The first program tessellates the terrain and stores it on the GPU using transform feedback. The second program uses the transform feedback buffer to render to shadow depth buffer. The third program uses the transform feedback buffer to draws the scene. This way I avoid tessellating the terrain twice.

To my surprise, the 2nd method was actually much slower until I started using the separation of the tessellation phase to tessellate the terrain less frequently. Now the methods are about the same fps, but in the 2nd method the terrain mesh is being updated less frequently.

Shouldnt the 2nd method be faster even if I tessellate every frame like the first method? The only thing I can think of is that the passthrough vertex shaders for the shadow and main program both have to copy 6,000,000*3 vertices even though they are just passthrough shaders. In the first method, the data would be passed right from tessellation shader to the fragment shader. So...

Does a passthrough vertex shader use the transform feedback buffer data directly, or does it copy every single vertice (even though it's the same), and use the copied data?

```
...
{
    out_position = in_position;
    out_normal = in_normal;
    out_uv = in_uv;
}
```

Is there any way I can speed this up?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit:

I should note that the example is for the shadow  program, the geometry shader applies different mvp matrices, culls, and asigns layers.

In the main program, I use 
    gl_Position=mvp*in_position;
to allow gl to cull back facing triangles, but the normals and uvs are still passthrough.

Comment: "*I should note that the example is for the shadow program, the geometry shader applies different mvp matrices, culls, and asigns layers.*" Then it's not a passthrough shader, now is it?

Comment: The main program vertex shader is a passthrough shader for only normals and uvs. The shadow program vertex shader is passthrough for everything.

Comment: I should add that the vertex info for the shadow program does not need clipping or culling. Every primitive is fully inside the frustum and backface culling happens manually in the geometry shader, because it is more efficient to do it there before the triangles are cascaded into layers.

Comment: "*backface culling happens manually in the geometry shader, because it is more efficient to do it there before the triangles are cascaded into layers.*" Never, *ever* believe that the Geometry Shader doing *anything* will be faster than actual hardware functionality. Not without an actual benchmark proving that this is the case. Doing frustum culling on triangles in the GS is basically throwing performance away.

Comment: I have tested it both ways, and culling in the geometry shader is slightly faster for my application.

Comment: Because CSM forms multiple ortho projections that capture different segments of the camera frustum from the perspective of the sun. The sun's normal is constant across all CSM frustums, so backface culling can happen for a triangle that would otherwise be duplicated for overlapping CSM frustums. I should note that only triangles that lie within the overlapping boundary of the frustums need to be duplicated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Does a passthrough vertex shader use the transform feedback buffer data directly, or does it copy every single vertice (even though it's the same), and use the copied data?

"the same" as what?

You told OpenGL to write 18 million vertices to a buffer object. Then you told OpenGL to render 18 million vertices which are stored in a buffer object. *Twice*. So that's what OpenGL is going to do.

How is it going to be able to render those 18 million vertices without reading them from memory? That's 36 *million* reads of vertex data. If your vertex data takes 32 bytes per vertex, that's over 1GB of data reading. Every frame.

Remember: the principle performance gain of tessellation is that you're reading and processing *less data*. By doing transform feedback reads of tessellated data, you're losing some of those performance benefits. Indeed, since transform feedback cannot generate optimized index lists, this will be *lower* in performance than if you had hand-tessellated the data and optimized it.

The reason your double-tessellation version is sometimes faster is because the cost of reading the expanded data twice (not to mention the cost of writing it) has exceeded the cost of doing the tessellation twice. And having to use a GS in your shadow render certainly isn't helping performance.

Comment: Transform feedback is stored on the gpu after the vertex shader. I understand that I need to do 36,000,000 reads. The transform feedback buffer is kept on the GPU after the tessellation evaluation phase, so the next logical phase would be a geometry or fragment shader. Thus, the information I need has already been "vertex shader processed", so I just write passthrough vertex shaders for the next 2 programs. Does the passthrough vertex shader copy data from gpu to gpu or just read from the buffer already on the gpu. Can I skip the vertex shading process?

Comment: By skip the vertex shader, I mean only the input/output phase of the vertex shader. Not the entire vertex processing pipeline.

Comment: @Kyy13: "*Can I skip the vertex shading process?*" Why do you think that matters? The cost is in *reading the data*. 1GB of data does not magically manifest itself into geometry shader registers. Regardless of who's reading that data, it must be read. And that's where your performance is going.

Comment: Because out_position = in_position is one read, and whatever the vertex shader does with out_position is more reads. Skipping the first read would be faster, but it requires the vertex shader to work with in_position directly, which is just a pointer and offset to the transform feedback buffer already on the gpu.

Comment: @Kyy13: "*which is just a pointer and offset to the transform feedback buffer already on the gpu.*" No, it's not. The variable is data *fetched* from that buffer. By the time the VS gets the `in` variable, the memory read has already happened. Even on AMD hardware, where VAOs have to be compiled into the VS, by the time your VS code executes, the data has already been fetched. And the same would be true if the VS could be skipped. The cost of reading from the buffer *cannot* be avoided, whether the VS or the GS were the top of the pipe.

Comment: "*whatever the vertex shader does with out_position is more reads.*" But those "more reads" are not reads of GPU main memory; they're reads from the memory storage used to communicate between the VS and the GS. Those reads involve much faster memory. They will not be the bottleneck in this process.

Comment: The GS can be skipped though... by not including a GS. A passthrough GS would be slower than no GS for the same reason. Is there no similar function for a vertex shader? Shouldnt the compiler be able to detect and optimize away that extra step?

Comment: Okay, got it. So maybe in the future there will be a way to store transform feedback on the fast gpu memory, but currently needs to be stored elsewhere and read back twice. Dam. Okay thank you :)

Comment: @Kyy13: "*So maybe in the future there will be a way to store transform feedback on the fast gpu memory*" The "faster memory" is faster because it's not very large. It's more than likely just the post-T&L cache (but of course, hardware varies), which is typically on the order of kilobytes in size. You're not going to store 32 *million* vertices in the post-T&L cache.

Comment: @Kyy13: Remember: GPUs are *pipelined*. They don't work by running the VS on all the data, then running the GS on the results of that, then running the FS on the results of that. It works by running them all in parallel, so that while vertex 4 is being processed by the VS, vertices 0,1,2 can be processed by the GS, and so forth. There doesn't need to be a lot of storage between stages.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So the data actually flows as a small number of vertices through the entire pipeline (vertex - fragment) shader then repeat? Is that what limits the output of the tessellation shader?

Comment: Okay thanks, already answered by the time I asked. That clears up a lot of confusion. Marked your answer as correct!